# NameError: name 'ElementNotVisibleException' is not defined Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i'm trying to make a little python script, but i keep getting the error codes:

```
 File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\selenium xpath testing.py", line 30, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='page-content']/section[1]/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/a[1]/i[1]").click()
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='page-content']/section[1]/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/a[1]/i[1]"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxa66gu8q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxa66gu8q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxa66gu8q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxa66gu8q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxa66gu8q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\selenium xpath testing.py", line 37, in <module>
    except (ElementNotVisibleException or NoSuchElementException) or (ElementNotVisibleException and NoSuchElementException):
NameError: name 'ElementNotVisibleException' is not defined
```

this is my code

```
count=0
while count < 100:
    #this both works
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='page-content']/section[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div/a[2]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='page-content']/section[1]/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/a[1]/i[1]").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.back()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.refresh()
        count +=1
        print(count)
    except (ElementNotVisibleException or NoSuchElementException) or (ElementNotVisibleException and NoSuchElementException):
        driver.back()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='page-content']/section[1]/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div/a[2]").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='page-content']/section[1]/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/a[1]/i[1]").click()
        count +=1
        print(count)
```

any ideas why it says ElementNotVisible is not defined when i'm handling it with an except?

When i just change the exception to exception:

I'm still getting

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\selenium xpath testing.py", line 44, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='page-content']/section[1]/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/a[1]/i[1]").click()
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 72, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 461, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3pqr2lvm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3pqr2lvm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3pqr2lvm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3pqr2lvm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/Users/Eddie/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3pqr2lvm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Comment: Try `selenium.ElementNotVisibleException`?

Comment: i'm getting NameError: name 'selenium' is not defined.

Comment: That means you didn't import it in that scope, or did you use an alias? (import as..)

Comment: i imported from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException